# A functor which prohibits extra morphisms between mapped objects

Tags: category-theory

Let $F: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is a functor with the following property. Any morphism $f: F(X) \to F(Y)$ in $\mathcal D$ factors only through objects mapped by $F$. In other words there is no object $Z \notin$ image of $F$, through which $f$ could be factored.

Does this functor property have some common name?

---

**UPDATE**

As an example let's consider a category $\mathcal C$ of data types (boolean, natural number, integer, real, ...) and a subtype relation defined on types. Let $F$ be a functor $Set$, which maps data types to corresponding set types (set of booleans, set of natural numbers, ...). For example there is a morphism $natural < real$ in $\mathcal C$. This morphism is mapped to the morphism $Set(natural) < Set(real)$. The last one can be factored only through $Set(integer)$. All morphisms between $Set(natural)$ and $Set(real)$ belongs to the image of $Set$.

Comment: So there is no condition on $f$ that is should also be in the image of $F$? If so then it looks more like a condition on a class of objects in $\mathcal D$.

Comment: Oh, it seems that my definition is overcomplicated. After addition of this condition it seems that it's just a full functor. Is it right?

Comment: If e.g. $\mathcal C$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal D$ and $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ is the inclusion functor then $F$ is a full functor. However it is still possible that a morphism $f=Ff:X=F(X)\to F(Y)=Y$ can be written as $f=g\circ h$ where $h:X\to Z$, $g:Z\to Y$ and $Z$ is not an object of $\mathcal C$ (hence does not belong to the image of $F$).

Comment: Agreed. I tried to describe this property on a concrete example. I updated the question. My categories are thin.

Comment: Your example makes your question less clear. Don't we have morphisms e.g. *natural$\to$complex$\to$real* as well?

Comment: There is no complex numbers in my categories. It's just a type system of some programming language. Let for simplicity the type system has only following types: void (a subtype of all other types), any (a super type of all other non-set types), boolean, natural numbers, integers (super type of nat) and real (super type of integer), set of void, set of any, ..., set of set of void, set of set of any, ... Subtype relation is an order. The property described in question states that Set(nat) is a subtype of Set(integer) or Set(real). And it's not subtype of integer or Set(Set(void))

Comment: $Set(nat)$ can be related to some non-set type. For example $Set(nat)$ is a super type of $void$. Or we can define a generic collection in the type system, such as $Set(X) < Collection(Y)$ iff $X < Y$. But my property states that if $Set(X) < Set(Y)$, then any object between this objects is always of the form $Set(Z)$, it belongs to the image of functor $Set$.